# constexpr with conditional statement error, using Stroustrup example

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 311 describes `constexpr fac` for factorial, which includes a conditional statement.  Then on Page 312, describes `constexpr bad2` with a conditional statement and a comment that it results in an error.  He also states on Page 312 that "A constexpr function allows recursion and conditional expressions."

What is the difference between the two functions and the conditional statement that result in the error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int fac(int n)
{
    return (n > 1) ? n*fac(n-1) : 1;
}

constexpr int bad2(int a)
{
    if (a>=0) return a; else return -a; // error: if-statement in constexpr function
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    constexpr int c = 3;
    cout << fac(c) << endl;
    cout << bad2(c) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and results:

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall test135.cc && ./a.out
6
3
```

`bad2` indeed results in an error in C++11 mode.

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall -std=c++11 test135.cc && ./a.out
test135.cc: In function ‘constexpr int bad2(int)’:
test135.cc:12:1: error: body of ‘constexpr’ function ‘constexpr int bad2(int)’ not a return-statement
 }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend picking up a more recent reference. This code (`bad2`) was invalid in c++11, but is valid from c++14.

Comment: Thanks. I added the compilation results.  Does C++11 result in error only on certain types of conditionals?  It appears that is resolved in g++ default C standard, which is C++14?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `if` is a `statement`, `?:` is an expression, so statements are not allowed (except a single return), but expressions are (you can nest the `?:`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before C++14, `if` statement can't be used in [`constexpr` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), and it could have exactly one `return` statement.

(until C++14)

> - the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain only the following:
>
>   - null statements (plain semicolons)
>   - static_assert declarations
>   - typedef declarations and alias declarations that do not define classes or enumerations
>   - using declarations
>   - using directives
>   - if the function is not a constructor, exactly one return statement

So until C++14 it was general to use conditional operator (instead of `if`) and recursion (instead of loop), and constrain in single `return` statement for `constexpr` functions.

Since C++14 using `if` statement, multiple `return` statements and loops are allowed.

Comment: RE: Before C++14, is the 'return (cond) ? x : y' a special case of conditional that is allowed?

Comment: @notaorb Using conditional operator is fine; and it satisfies the requirement *only one return statement*.